# Django - понятие о связи таблиц

Tags: python, django

Допустим, в Django я хочу создать 3 модели баз данных Comment, Post и User.
Хочу, чтобы к одному посту могли быть прикреплены несколько комментариев и
у одного юзера могло быть несколько комментариев. Но у одного комментария не могло быть разных постов и юзеров. Нужно ли мне в таком случае использовать ForeignKey или ManyToManyFild?

```
class User(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    register_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)

class Сomment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)# или ManyToManyField
    data = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Сomment)# или ForeignKey
    like = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом случае `ManyToManyField` не подходит, так как такой тип поля нужен для моделирования ситуации, когда один комментарий может относиться к нескольким постам и у одного поста может быть несколько комментариев.

Нужно использовать `ForeignKey`:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
  text = models.TextField()
  author = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    # параметр related_name нужен, если хотите 
    # чтобы из модели User можно было достать все комментарии
    related_name='comments', 
    #если коллекция комментариев в User не нужна - укажите 
    # вместо имени '+' как в следующей строке
    #related_name='+',
  )
  post = models.ForeignKey(
    Post,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='comments'
  )
  data = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    like = models.IntegerField()
```

Обратите внимание, что в `Post` не создаем поля для `comments`. Это поле создается, используя атрибут `related_name` на поле `ForeignKey` в `Comment`. Доставать коментарии данного поста можно так:

```
post = ... # как-то нашли пост
comments = post.comments.all()
```